# Verify if Google Email is being sent in ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I've been reading a bunch into angular and I'm really new into it. I've been asked to develop this app for the company I work in where users need to login using their Google Credentials.

So far this is cake, but I think I'm complicating myself too much. So far, here's what I have:

- Google Button to login
- Callback function that will save the email to a variable and send an AJAX request to save it on database and start session

Problems:

- Google Api says it cannot find the callback function. I'm pretty sure it's something really simple, but I can't really seem to find it.

Here is my relevant angular code:

```
app.controller('LoginController', function($scope){
        $scope.authResultErrorMessage = "";
        $scope.showAuthResultErrorMessage = false;
        $scope.userEmail = "";
        $scope.handleSignIn = function(authResult){
            console.log("I was called!");
            if(authResult){
                if(authResult['error'] != undefined){
                    $scope.showAuthResultErrorMessage = true;
                    $scope.authResultErrorMessage = "Hubo un error. Intente de nuevo. Si este error persiste, ponganse en contacto con el director de IT.";
                } else if(authResult['error'] === undefined){
                    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', loadProfileFromGoogle);
                }
            }
        };
        $scope.loadProfileFromGoogle = function(){
            var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get( {'userId' : 'me'} );
            request.execute(getEmail);
            console.log(request);
        };
        $scope.getEmail = function(obj){
            $scope.userEmail = obj['emails'].filter(function(v){
                return v.type === 'account';
            })[0].value;
            console.log($scope.userEmail);
            $scope.verifyUser($scope.userEmail);
        };
        $scope.verifyUser = function(email){
            $.get('controllers/verifyUser.php', {
                data: email,
            }, function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                    JSON.parse(result);
            });
        };
    });
```

Here's the html code:

```
<div ng-controller="LoginController as login">
    <span id="signin-button">
        <span
            class="g-signin"
            data-callback="login.handleSignIn"
            ng-click="login.handleSignIn"
            data-approvalprompt="force"
            data-clientid="201763423039-kdogu6vm1fgsj6hdnafn5k9otkj9ekjj.apps.googleusercontent.com"
            data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
            data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
            data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read">
        </span>
    </span>   
</div>
```

When I click the button, everything goes smoothly, I login, but on the console, the following message shows:

> Callback function named "login.handleSignIn" not found cb=gapi.loaded_0:484

I've been smashing my head for a couple of hours now trying to figure out why the function is not being called, or for that matter, if there's a syntax erro currently not being highligted that exists. If anyone could help, I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Is the callback "login.handleSignIn" accessible to GAPI? It's a function defined in your AngularJS controller, it won't be accessible to GAPI if it's running outside the context of AngularJS. I'm guessing you're not seeing "I was called" in the console, is that correct?

Comment: This problem was already solved, but yes I was not able to see "I was called"

Answer (score 0):

Why don't try this directive :

http://jeradbitner.com/angular-directive.g-signin/